# Laravel - Midlleware called after controller construct

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, middleware, laravel-middleware

EDIT: Better example

I have trouble with checkauth controller that are called after SectionsController constructor - from this is extended ReportController and I don't know why it works like this.
I try add middleware at the start of SectionController costruct like       *$this->middleware('checkauth');* but not working too.

Middleware

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Auth;


class CheckAuth
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (!Auth::check())
        {
            return redirect('/admin/login')->withErrors(['message' => 'You need to login before proceeding']);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

SectionsController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\RMReport;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile;



class SectionsController extends BaseController
{
  use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;

   protected $user;

    public function __construct(){
      $this->middleware('checkauth');

      dump("SECTIONSCONTROLLER: ");
      dump(\Auth::check());

     //PROBLEM HERE - \Auth::Check is false , \Auth::user is null
     $this->user = \Auth::user();

     if( !$this->user->can('something') ) return redirect()->route('someroute');
}
}
```

ReportController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\RMReport\Form;

use App\Http\Controllers\RMReport\SectionsController;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;


class ReportController extends SectionsController
{

    public function form(){
      if( $this->user->status != 'Active'){
        return something;
      }
    return another something;
    }

}
```

Output from route:list

```
GET|HEAD | admin/remote-report/{id?} | rm.report | App\Http\Controllers\RMReport\Form\ReportController@form | web,checkauth,checkownerRMreport |  
POST | admin/remote-report/{id?} | rm.report | App\Http\Controllers\RMReport\Form\ReportController@store | web,checkauth,checkownerRMreport |
```

Output on call GET

```
"SECTIONSCONTROLLER: "

false

"CHECKAUTH:"

true
```

Comment: Are you just wondering why `dump(\Auth::check());` is `false` even though it's called after the `->middleware('checkauth')`call or is there more to your code?

Comment: Thanks for response. I need save in construct information about user (user object and some relations). From this Controller (`SectionsController`) inherit other controllers (for example `ReportController`) and then I need work in this controllers with this information.
So yes, i am wondering why is `false` and how to call middleware before controller for next work with `Auth` informations in controller construct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Understanding the `Laravel` lifecycle and the object lifecycle is important. When creating an new object the constructor will be called before anything else. When the action of new SectionsController() happens, it will trigger the constructor immediately, since the constructor calls the middleware, it has no way of knowing that it should run before.

This means that in the request lifecycle, the controller constructor has to be before the middlewares. This luckily has been solved and if you use a callback for middleware dependent logic in the constructor, you will avoid this problem.

```
$this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
    dump("SECTIONSCONTROLLER: ");
    dump(\Auth::check());
});
```

**EDIT**
Instead of doing all that you are doing in the constructor which is wrong, you can utilize the `Laravel` middleware for policies. This require you to use the Authorize middleware, which by standard is enabled.

```
$this->middleware('can:something');
```

Comment: Thank you for reponse... this work for dump but when I need work with Autch::check in construct after that callback, i have same result. Probably I don't understand Laravel lifecycle properly. I thought that when I define the middlware's in routes (grouped routes or in route itself or in controller construct) will be middleware created before controller class and than is called controller class construct. 
Also If I call $this->middleware('checkauth') in construct, it's is not callback for CheckAuth middleware? It's give me same result

Comment: you need to do your work in the callback, what are you trying to do then? your code example does not include that, come with an example

Comment: Thank a lot for help, but for interest, when someone need work with user this way like I give example, can be this doing somehow?

Comment: I would argue what you are trying to do in the constructor is wrong and should be done in middlewares, constructor should not handle redirects but the instantiating of your controller.